# How to exclude response validation of swagger API for images?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I have a Swagger YAML function such as :

```
/acitem/image:         
    x-swagger-router-controller: image_send
    get:
      description: Returns 'image' to the caller
      operationId: imageSend
      parameters:
        - name: name
          in: query
          description: The image to be sent
          required: false
          type: string      
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:            
            # $ref: "#/definitions/ImageResponse"
            type: string
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

I have the Content Type Produces as :

```
produces:
  - application/json    
  - text/plain
  - text/html
  - image/png
```

But even after that I have swagger validation error as 
[image]

My Question is - 
is there an optimized method to write the image response or is there a way to exclude my image response validation ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here:

```
      responses:
    "200":
      description: Success
      schema:            
        # $ref: "#/definitions/ImageResponse"
        type: string
```

you already defined the schema response structure using $ref, you dont need 'type: string'

also, the error could be related with the definition of ImageResponse

Comment: I have commented the ref schema also the problem is I am getting the Image successfully but at the backend i am getting as response validation failed

Comment: could you provide some links with the whole YAML definition and the backend code?